# Redirect after login in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, redirect, symfony-2.1, symfony-security

In Symfony 2 you can set up a target for the logout so that after logout you will be redirected to `/main`. However with the login you will be redirected to `/`. Is there a manner to setup a target for a (successful) login as well?

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/m/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/m
        form_login:
            check_path: /m/login_check
            login_path: /m/login
        logout:
            path:   /m/logout
            target: /main
        anonymous: ~
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `target_path` option. Using your example above:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        form_login:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /loggedinpage
```

With the above the user will always be redirected to `/loggedinpage` upon a successful login.  Details of all the options for the security component are available in the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) (albeit slightly hidden away!)

Comment: Thanks for the (deep-) link to the Symfony docs for further details!

Comment: Also I would have thought that the default_target_path is always used when you didn't request a secured route before. Unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: what if i want to pass the locale to the route ?