# symfony 2 security redirect after login

Tags: php, symfony, acl

I have the next security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Test\BackEndBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 10

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: TestBackEndBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                check_path: _security_check
                login_path: _security_login
                default_target_path: homepage
            logout: true
            security: true
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/service, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /.*, roles: {ROLE_PARTNER, ROLE_ADMIN} }
```

And the next routing:

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: TestBackEndBundle:Default:index }

_security_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: TestBackEndBundle:Security:login }

_security_check:
    pattern:  /login_check

_security_logout:
    pattern:  /logout
```

Authentication works well, instead of redirection after login. Application redirects to **/_wdt/5044c6f2a329c**. How can I make redirect to the home page? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to create a **success_handler** implementing the [AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.html)
2. Then you have to declare it as a service (in services.xml or services.yml)
3. And add it to your [security configuration.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)

Comment: That seems to be the right way to do it, but how can we inherit the [checks already implemented](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php#L88) on the [`DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.2/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php) ? I mean do we have to re-implement them ?

Answer (score 12):

The solution is to unprotect your _wdt route.

You get this behaviour because your _wdt route is protected. 
When a page loads the toolbar from the _wdt route, it triggers the login. Your login form will try to redirect back to the route that triggered the login: In this case _wdt.

Add this to your access_control in security.yml

```
 - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
```

This will let the toolbar work in both protected and unprotected pages, and if the page is protected, it will be the page the one who triggers the login form = it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can set `always_use_default_target_path: true` and then your `default_target_path` will work as you expect. See [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8374854/541961).